# A bind with a port of zero will bind you to a free port. Is this portable?

Tags: c, sockets, bind, portability, port

I want my program to bind to a free port.

Google told me that a bind with port=0 will do that, but I haven't found if this is guaranteed to work on any system (Windows/Linux in particular).

Can someone link a doc that say that?

Comment: Shouldn't you skip the bind() call, if you want ephemeral port to be selected?

Comment: @CodePainters - not on a receiving socket, no.

Comment: @Alnitak Hmm, at least on Linux it works as I expected (just verified) - skipping bind(), and using socket()/listen()/accept() results in a listening socket using ephemeral port. I'm not sure about Win32, however.

Comment: yes, according to "TCP/IP Illustrated vol 2" it looks like the 4.2BSD code does an implicit bind to an ephemeral port if you don't bind yourself.

Comment: Why not just check the documentation? The answer is Yes to windows https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737550(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Alnitak `man 7 ip` says an ephemeral port is allocated on bind, listen, connect or sendto.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking for documentation is out of the scope of this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's universal as far as I know, but I can't find any text in the standards that says it is. An alternative that might be more portable is using `getaddrinfo` with null service name pointers and the `AI_PASSIVE` flag. This is guaranteed to give you an `sockaddr` you can `bind` to. It's also the correct way to let the administrator choose which local ip (v4 or v6)
address to bind to.

Answer (score 8):

It's standard, documented behavior for AF_INET address family:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html

See ip_local_port_range, which contains the following:

```
    An ephemeral port is allocated to a socket in the following circumstances:

          *  the port number in a socket address is specified as 0 when
             calling bind(2);
```

Answer (score 5):

It's certainly "standard" in the 4.2BSD socket API from which most every other implementation is derived, but I'm not aware of any formal specification that actually says so.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
int main()
{
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    socklen_t addrLen;
    int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (fd == -1) {
        printf("Failed to create socket");
    }
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = 0; 
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
    if (bind(fd, (const struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1) {
        printf("Failed to bind");
    }
    addrLen = sizeof(addr);
    if (getsockname(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, &addrLen) == -1) {
        printf("getsockname() failed");
    }
    printf("port=%d \n", addr.sin_port);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question is not “how might I write a program that attempts to bind to port 0?” but rather “is the behavior of binding to port 0 specified by any standard?”. This does not appear to answer the question.