# Automatic port number assignment using getaddrinfo()

Tags: sockets, udpclient

*(Socket programming)*C-code for client (passing messages through UDP) is given below. We can automatically assign port number to socket by

1. not calling bind() before sendto() [(related post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075399/how-to-bind-to-any-available-port)
2. binding with port 0 (only provided in windows and solaris documentation for bind) that makes the kernel do automatic assignment.[realted post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895751/a-bind-with-a-port-of-zero-will-bind-you-to-a-free-port-is-this-portable)

However doing the same with getaddrinfo() function,passing "0"(port number) as 2nd argument assigns port 0 to socket and not any USER_RESERVED port.

How to achieve automatic port assignment using getaddrinfo()?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<netdb.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    struct addrinfo client,*cl;
    int status;


    memset(&client,0,sizeof(client));//stucture should be empty

    client.ai_family=AF_INET;
    client.ai_socktype=SOCK_DGRAM;
    client.ai_flags=AI_PASSIVE;

    if(getaddrinfo(INADDR_ANY,"0",&client,&cl)!=0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"getaddrinfo: %s\n",gai_strerror(status));
        return 2;
    }

    int s;
    //printf("Port:: %d\n",((struct sockaddr_in*)(cl->ai_addr))->sin_port); //checking protocol number
    s=socket(cl->ai_family,cl->ai_socktype,cl->ai_protocol);
    //printf("Port:: %d\n",((struct sockaddr_in*)(cl->ai_addr))->sin_port); //checking protocol number

    //bind(s,cl->ai_addr,cl->ai_addrlen);
    //printf("Port:: %d\n",((struct sockaddr_in*)(cl->ai_addr))->sin_port); //checking protocol number

    struct sockaddr_in server;
    server.sin_family=AF_INET;
    inet_pton(AF_INET,argv[1],&(server.sin_addr));
    server.sin_port=htons(4169);
    char str[100];
    for(int i=2;i<argc;i++)
    {
        strncat(str,argv[i],strlen(argv[i]));
        str[strlen(str)]=' ';
    }

    sendto(s,str,strlen(str),0,(struct sockaddr *)&server,(socklen_t)sizeof(server));
    //printf("Port:: %d\n",((struct sockaddr_in*)(cl->ai_addr))->sin_port); //checking protocol number

    close(s);
}
```

Comment: `getaddrinfo` provides information about the intended destination, specified by the first two arguments.  It plays absolutely no part in any local port assignment.

Comment: getaddrinfo provides information not just about the intended destination, but can also be used to populate struct addr_info for creating and binding sockets to ports. I have added link to the two methods i have mentioned in the question,none of them uses getaddrinfo(). @ottomeister

Comment: When passing a numeric value in the `service` parameter, including `"0"`, you should be including the `AI_NUMERICSERV` flag. Also, the `node` parameter expects a null-terminated string. Passing `INADDR_ANY` works only because it is defined as `0` and `0` can be passed to a `char*` pointer. Documented behavior is to pass in `NULL` if you want the returned addresses to use `INADDR_ANY`. Don't use macros for purposes they are not intended for, and `INADDR_ANY` is not intended to be passed into `getaddrinfo()` like this

Comment: The question says it's about client-side use.  On the client side you typically only use `getaddrinfo` to obtain the server address, to be passed to a `sendto` or `connect` call.  In any case, the reason you're getting a port value of zero in the `sockaddr` result is that that's what you're telling `getaddrinfo` to construct by passing it `"0"` as the second argument.  The actual assignment of a port is made only by a later call (`bind`, `connect`, ...) that operates on the socket.  That's the point when a port value of 0 is interpreted as "pick a port for me".

Comment: BTW, if the reason you're asking this question is that you want to know which port has been assigned, you can use `getsockname` to obtain that information after you've made the call that causes the port assignment to happen.